# what is mean by *adj and how it is working

Tags: c++

I started working with the C++ STL and I am learnimg about `list`.

I know that in `list<int> adj`, `adj` is an object of `list` class in which `int` are stored.

My doubt is, what is mean by `*adj` in `list<int> *adj;`?

Comment: *adj is a pointer to a list of ints

Answer (score 2):

This declares `adj` to be a pointer to a `list<int>`:

```
list<int> *adj;
```

It does not construct a `list<int>` but can be used to point at `list<int>`s constructed elsewhere in the program. Example:

```
list<int> a_list_int_instance;

adj = &a_list_int_instance; // & is the "address-of" operator in this context
```

`adj` now points at `a_list_int_instance` and can access its methods by *dereferencing*. Here are two options:

```
adj->push_back(10);
(*adj).push_back(20);
```